# I want to insert value "number" like "1,2,3,4,5" into my sqlite table. Depending on the search i do

Tags: android, sqlite

1.This is my code snippet which I have written in **DBController**:

```
public boolean insertReport(String item_ean) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd      HH:mm:ss");      
    Date date=new Date();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ITEM_EAN, item_ean);
    contentValues.put(DATE,dateFormat.format(date));
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_REPORT, null, contentValues);
    if (result==-1){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

2.This is in my **MainActivity** class

```
boolean isInserted = dbcontroller.insertReport(editText.getText().toString());

if (isInserted = true){
    Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

selected = pselected;
textView.setText("ITEM UNKNOWN");
selected.clear();
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

So in the above code I'm giving a number i.e **12345678**, it searches in the database. If the number is not found, then it shows **ITEM UNKNOWN**. Now I want to insert numbers depending on the search result. If item is unknown then I should insert "5" into the table. It is for my reference.

Comment: It looks like you're inserting not searching. If you would like to have some logic after searching, can you provide your search class?

Comment: Yes Daniel, the code that i have posted above is for insertion only.Thing is i'm searching for a value through editText and i'm insert that same value into the DB. It's working fine. Only thing is when i'm inserting the value from editText i need to insert a number as well. For unknown item number is "5", known item number "1". TABLE_NAME is reports. it has three columns NUMBER-which is the input from editText.
Date.
Prediction_type-"5" "3" "1".....
So i want insert into prediction_type..

Comment: Okay, so if I understand you correctly. You couldn't use `contentValues.put(Prediction_type, number);` in the insertion method because you don't know at that point if the item is found or not, correct?

Comment: if i use contentValues.put(Prediction_type, prediction); it says prediction not initialised. if i initialise it to 0 then the value inserted will be 0.

Comment: Right, you should query the database in the insertion method and then use the result with an if statement to initialize prediction. Your query should something like this: `Cursor cursor = db.query(reports, new String[]{"NUMBER"}, "NUMBER = ?", new String[]{item_ean}, null, null, null);`. Then use `cursor.getCount();`. If you get one as a result it found the item, so prediction can be initialized as 1 and if you get zero then prediction can be initialized as 5.

Comment: Since i'm new to this!
What will be my code in the main activity???
how will i insert "5" if item is unknown?
and "1" if item is known??

Comment: You know, the more I think about it the more I find something confusing. Why don't you initialize prediction to 1 regardless? If the insertion succeeds, then the prediction type would already be inserted as one because the item is technically "known" at that point. If the insertion fails, then no record would be added, so there wouldn't be a place to put 5 in. Why would you want to put 5 as the prediction type for an item that is technically "known"?

Comment: I'm not clear enough then. 
I'm maintaining a  report table for my ref ok!
If the item is unknown i'll insert number as 5. so that later when i see the table i should know that this item was unknown. If the the item is present then it is 1.Also i have a code which predicts for the nearest item. That is through toggle button. If the item is predicted right then it is 2. if not then 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the conditions you have mentioned in the comments, you have to modify your `insertReport` like so:

```
public boolean insertReport(String item_ean) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd      HH:mm:ss");
    Date date=new Date();
    long result;

    // This line queries your DB to see if the item_ean already exists, 1 means yes, 0 means no
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_REPORT,
            new String[]{"NUMBER"}, "NUMBER = ?",
            new String[]{item_ean}, null, null, null);

    // Value is already present, no need to insert again but you need to 
    // update the prediction value to 1 from 5
    if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(prediction, "1");
        result = db.update(TABLE_REPORT, contentValues, "NUMBER = ?", new String[]{item_ean});
    } 
    // Value is not present because getCount was 0.
    else {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ITEM_EAN, item_ean);
        contentValues.put(DATE,dateFormat.format(date));
        contentValues.put(prediction, "5");
        result = db.insert(TABLE_REPORT, null, contentValues);
    }
    if (result==-1){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I am assuming that `item_ean` is unique, therefore, the `db.query` will only ever find one or none and return a `cursor` with a `count` value of 1 or 0.